# Не выводит пришедшие данные

Tags: android, клиент-сервер, android-volley

Пишу приложение под android и использую библиотеку volley. Надо записать в `mTextViewResult` пришедшие данные. Как это сделать?

```
{"location":{"name":"Paris","region":"Ile-de-France","country":"France"}}
```

Сам код

```
try {
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("location");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject location = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
String name = location.getString("name");
String region = location.getString("region");
String country = location.getString("country");
mTextViewResult.append(name + ", " + region + ", " + country + "\n\n");
}
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: а вообще что-то приходит? я не в том плане что в логах видно ответ, я спрашиваю про то что вы можете вытащить из ответа. Попробуйте вывести в логи хотя-бы одну из ваших переменных

Comment: JSONArray - `[ ]`, **JSONObject - `{ }`**

Comment: Я пробовал ставить `JSONObject ` не работает